# Unable to retrieve JSON array with AngularJS $resource

Tags: json, angularjs, spring, ngresource

I've been trying retrieve values from JSON and so far, been unsuccessful. It does get called on the front-end when I refresh the page, but the information is not passing to the next method. I think the issue might be down to the `promises.push...` line, as I've tried to debug the method underneath and the information is not being passed on at all.

AngularJS:

```
var promises = [];
promises.push(SpringDataRestService.get({"collection": "subjects"}).$promise);

// Require each of these queries to complete before continuing
$q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
    // Grab the first result
    $scope.available = data[0].subjects;
    $scope.selected = [];
    // If this is an update, get the second result in set
    if (data.length > 1) {
        // For each permission that is assigned to this role, add ID (name) to selected
        for (var i = 0; i < data[1].data.subjects.length; i++) {
            var perm = data[1].data.subjects[i];
            $scope.selected.push(perm.name);
        }
    }
    $scope.tableEditOptions = new NgTableParams({}, {
        dataset: $scope.available
    });
   $scope.available, 'name');
}).catch(function (data) {
  // ERROR
});
```

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "name": "FWGWG",
    "description": "WGWGWG",
    "lockId": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "QFQFQF",
    "description": "QFQFQFQ",
    "lockId": 0
  }
]
```

I'm confident as well my for loop is wrong due to assigning the values as well, since I don't think it should be `data.subjects`, but I understand these threads are only 1 issue per question. Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `query` method for arrays:

```
var promise = SpringDataRestService.query({"collection": "subjects"}).$promise;

promise.then(function (dataArr) {
    console.log(dataArr);
    //...
}).catch(function (errorResponse) {
    console.log(errorResponse);        
});
```

With the REST services, the `get` method returns a JavaScript object and the `query` method returns a JavaScript array.

From the Docs:

> ### `$resource` Returns
>
> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally extended with custom actions. **The default set contains these actions:**
>
> ```
> {
>   'get':    {method: 'GET'},
>   'save':   {method: 'POST'},
>   'query':  {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
>   'remove': {method: 'DELETE'},
>   'delete': {method: 'DELETE'}
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> It is important to realize that invoking a `$resource` object method immediately returns an empty reference **(object or array depending on `isArray`).** Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `$resource` Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)